# cannot compare pdf files

Tags: bbedit

I have two pdf files under version control. When I use textwrangler to compare the difference I see jibberish fonts. I have attached the figure below:

Please suggest what can be done to solve this. thanks.

[image: my outputs]

Answer (score 1):

PDFs are not natively readable with TextWrangler.

[Adobe has a paid version of Acrobat that can compare two PDF files. There is a free trial available if this is a one-off need to compare PDFs.](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/compare-documents.html)

[This question may also be related to this StackExchange post.](https://superuser.com/questions/46123/how-to-compare-the-differences-between-two-pdf-files-on-windows)

Comment: thanks for your answer. But I was wondering, why can't I do that with TextWrangler? I could compare other text files with it but why not the pdfs?

Comment: See above. PDF is not text. You can open nearly anything in a text editor, but it won’t necessarily be readable. (Also, might want to switch to BBEdit, as Textwrangler is discontinued - same functionality, painless switch, keeps your preferences, you can turn off the paid features so they don’t show in menus!)

Answer (score 0):

You should open the files in Acrobat Reader. There is a compare option in Reader that allows you to compare two pdf files.

There is also an online site called [Draftable](https://draftable.com/compare) where you can compare 2 files online. It's free and simple to use.

Comment: thanks for your answer. But I was wondering, why can't I do that with TextWrangler? I could compare other text files with it but why not the pdfs?

Comment: Well, pdfs are not text files.